# Is there a way to get Asio working without Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I know there is a version of ASIO that is not included in the Boost namespace, but even then ASIO depends on Boost, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get ASIO to work without dependencies on Boost (because I cannot include Boost into the project, for too many reasons).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, i don't believe so. ASIO has been using boost for as long as i have heard of it. I think they're very much interconnected. But you may be interested in a tool, [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html), which lets you extract the minimal subset of boost required for the libraries that you want to use.

Comment: Had no idea such a tool existed, simply awesome, I'd triple upvote this answer if I could :)

Comment: The idea of asio was always to be available in independent form from boost. And it is. Google for 'think asio' or the authors blog..

Comment: Or you can use the boost `NO_LIBS` defines to exclude non-header only libraries. I am using header only asio with header only boost. What's there to complain about? Nothing extra to compile.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a non-boost version of Asio:

> Asio comes in two variants: (non-Boost) Asio and Boost.Asio.

See:

http://think-async.com/Asio/

Comment: But it still requires a ton of boost headers, even though its not part of boost, I was also fooled by the name

Comment: Frankly I don's see which headers you are aiming at.. It has its own thread bits..

Comment: -1 Downvoting. This isn't true, **asio still requires header only boost files.** The reason for separation was because asio already has a huge namespace, and adding boost just makes it longer. Also asio is updated on a different release schedule than boost, and some people feel the need to update asio more frequently than boost. Finally, to use ASIO without `boost::bind()` seems near impossible!

Comment: This may have changed since I last used ASIO. Historically, ASIO definitely has required boost. Now I don't see a mention of that dependency...

Comment: actually now that C++11 has lambdas boost::bind() is not needed

Answer (score 2):

The "non-boost asio" has its own thread bits instead of using boost.thread, but it still requires boost.date_time, boost.array, boost.utility, boost.bind, boost.shared_ptr...

There is no version of Asio that can work without any Boost dependency.

Comment: Most part of TR1 right and majority of compilers already support it. And the date-time I'm not sure whether there was an option to run from it.. can't recall.

Comment: just recalled boost.system being one to get rid of.. memory fails me.

Answer (score 1):

Recent ASIO versions can work without Boost in a standalone mode. This mode was probably enabled by the C++11 support of the library because it can now use standard threads, futures, etc instead of their Boost implementation. You can simply include ASIO like below and enjoy:

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
```